# What is the preferred syntax for initializing a dict: curly brace literals {} or the dict() function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm putting in some effort to learn Python, and I am paying close attention to common coding standards.  This may seem like a pointlessly nit-picky question, but I am trying to focus on best-practices as I learn, so I don't have to unlearn any 'bad' habits later.

I see two common methods for initializing a dict:

```
a = {
    'a': 'value',
    'another': 'value',
}

b = dict( 
    a='value',
    another='value',
)
```

Which is considered to be "more pythonic"?  Which do you use? Why?

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  Where did you see examples that lead to confusion?

Comment: Well, I've been using the Python tutorial, Dive into Python and then a variety of blogs, SO posts and other Googled resources.  The official docs use `{}` pretty uniformly, but I see a lot of the explicit `dict()` approach elsewhere.  I could see the benefit of an explicit syntax, but the absence of the approach in the official docs made me suspicious.  After posting this I looked at the library docs for `dict` and found the caution that keys must be valid identifiers when an explicit `dict` is used to initialize a dict.

Comment: How is "dict()" more explicit than "{}"?  I'm not understanding your confusion.  Both seem explicit to me.  Can you provide a quote or reference that makes you say "dict" is "explicit" and "{}" is not explicit?  Where do you think this distinction arose from?

Comment: The distinction is spelling.  `dict()` is spelled `dict`--it uses the name of the type.  The braces (`{}`) rely on punctuation to identify the type.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Curly braces. Passing keyword arguments into `dict()`, though it works beautifully in a lot of scenarios, can only initialize a map if the keys are valid Python identifiers.

### This works:

```
a = {'import': 'trade', 1: 7.8}
```

```
a = dict({'import': 'trade', 1: 7.8})
```

### This won't work:

```
a = dict(import='trade', 1=7.8)
```

It will result in the following error:

```
    a = dict(import='trade', 1=7.8)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 100):

The first, curly braces. Otherwise, you run into consistency issues with keys that have odd characters in them, like `=`.

```
# Works fine.
a = {
    'a': 'value',
    'b=c': 'value',
}

# Eeep! Breaks if trying to be consistent.
b = dict( 
    a='value',
    b=c='value',
)
```

Comment: This is exactly why one might prefer the dict() method for initialization, it forces the dictionary keys to be valid identifiers, so they are compatible with, for example, **kwargs, and keys are valid attribute names.

Answer (score 65):

The first version is preferable:

- It works for all kinds of keys, so you can, for example, say `{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}`. The second variant only works for (some) string keys. Using different kinds of syntax depending on the type of the keys would be an unnecessary inconsistency.
- It is faster:

  ```
  $ python -m timeit "dict(a='value', another='value')"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.79 usec per loop
  $ python -m timeit "{'a': 'value','another': 'value'}"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.305 usec per loop
  ```
- If the special syntax for dictionary literals wasn't intended to be used, it probably wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

I almost always use curly-braces; however, in some cases where I'm writing tests, I do keyword packing/unpacking, and in these cases dict() is much more maintainable, as I don't need to change:

```
a=1,
b=2,
```

to:

```
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
```

It also helps in some circumstances where I think I might want to turn it into a namedtuple or class instance at a later time.

In the implementation itself, because of my obsession with optimisation, and when I don't see a particularly huge maintainability benefit, I'll always favour curly-braces.

In tests and the implementation, I would never use dict() if there is a chance that the keys added then, or in the future, would either:

- Not always be a string
- Not only contain digits, ASCII letters and underscores
- Start with an integer (`dict(1foo=2)` raises a SyntaxError)

Answer (score 3):

I think the first option is better because you are going to access the values as a['a'] or a['another']. The keys in your dictionary are strings, and there is no reason to pretend they are not. To me the keyword syntax looks clever at first, but obscure at a second look. This only makes sense to me if you are working with `__dict__`, and the keywords are going to become attributes later, something like that.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, in case you need to add attributes to your dictionary (things that are attached to the dictionary, but are not one of the keys), then you'll need the second form.  In that case, you can initialize your dictionary with keys having arbitrary characters, one at a time, like so:

```
    class mydict(dict): pass
    a = mydict()        
    a["b=c"] = 'value'
    a.test = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `dict()` is a good choice:

```
a=dict(zip(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri'], [x for x in range(1, 6)]))
```

Comment: There is an enumerate function that could do this better. For that matter, there is an Enum type that can do what you are doing here better. Also, this isn't really an answer to the question at all.

Comment: Same as:
`{x:y for x,y in zip(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri'], [x for x in range(1, 6)])}`