# Put target function's named arguments into multiprocessing.Process with key=value syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

We have a standard function syntax for passing keyword arguments. We can call `foo(arg_1=value1, arg_2=value2)` and this works well. But it doesn't work when I try to put arguments into `multiprocessing.Process`.

This expression `multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(arg_1=value1, arg_2=value2))` causes exception:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I put 'named' arguments into the process (to avoid data entering error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Process` expects a tuple as the `args` argument which is passed as positional arguments to the `target` function. If you want to pass keyword arguments to `target`, you have to provide a dictionary as the `kwargs` argument to `multiprocessing.Process`.

If you want to use the `key=value` syntax, instead of providing a dictionary literal `{'arg1': value1, 'arg2': value2}` you can use the [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) constructor:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, kwargs=dict(arg_1=value1, arg_2=value2))
```

Note that it has some limitations, see [What is the preferred syntax for initializing a dict: curly brace literals {} or the dict() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853683/what-is-the-preferred-syntax-for-initializing-a-dict-curly-brace-literals-or)